# Create shadow element which overlap adjacent element

Tags: html, css

html `<li>` shadow is not appearing due to adjecent `<li>` element. How can I make it glow.

it looks like this :-
[image]

```
<li style="box-shadow: 9px 8px 8px 10px rgba(9,180,219, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(9,180,219, 0.19);"><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=edatabase" class="waves-effect grey lighten-4" style="color:white; background: #4776e6; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #4776e6, #8e54e9); background: linear-gradient(to right, #4776e6, #8e54e9);">Employee Database<i class="material-icons">list</i></a></li>
<li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=attendance_report" class="waves-effect grey lighten-4">Attendance Report<i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></a></li>
<li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=shrinkage" class="waves-effect grey lighten-4">Shrinkage Report<i class="material-icons">chat</i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the item styled with this:

```
z-index: 1000;
position: relative; 
background-color: #ACFF32;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
```